# Adding an implicit broadcast exception?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-source, android-broadcast

I've been digging through AOSP code, and I'm trying to locate where [implicit broadcast exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) are defined. Ultimately, I'd like to both understand how certain broadcasts are allowed and add an additional one.

I've tried grep-ing some of the exempted broadcasts hoping to find a list of them to understand how they are exempted, but I have not had any luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As my experience in AOSP 9.0.0_r35, there is not a defination for list of implicit broadcast exceptions in AOSP source code.

By default broadcasts do not go to stopped apps. (please refer to file `ActivityManagerService.java,` function `broadcastIntentLocked`)

```
final int broadcastIntentLocked(ProcessRecord callerApp,
            String callerPackage, Intent intent, String resolvedType,
            IIntentReceiver resultTo, int resultCode, String resultData,
            Bundle resultExtras, String[] requiredPermissions, int appOp, Bundle bOptions,
            boolean ordered, boolean sticky, int callingPid, int callingUid, int userId) {
        intent = new Intent(intent);
        
    ...
    // By default broadcasts do not go to stopped apps.
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    ...
}
```

For the implicit broadcast exceptions, the AOSP manually add flag `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_INCLUDE_BACKGROUND` or `Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` everywhere the broadcast intent is sent. These flags are defined in Intent.java as below

```
/**
 * If set, this intent will always match any components in packages that
 * are currently stopped.  This is the default behavior when
 * {@link #FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES} is not set.  If both of these
 * flags are set, this one wins (it allows overriding of exclude for
 * places where the framework may automatically set the exclude flag).
 */
public static final int FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES = 0x00000020;

  /**
 * If set, the broadcast will always go to manifest receivers in background (cached
 * or not running) apps, regardless of whether that would be done by default.  By
 * default they will only receive broadcasts if the broadcast has specified an
 * explicit component or package name.
 *
 * NOTE: dumpstate uses this flag numerically, so when its value is changed
 * the broadcast code there must also be changed to match.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_RECEIVER_INCLUDE_BACKGROUND = 0x01000000;
```

For example of `ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED`, it is sent in AlarmManagerService.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING
        | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_INCLUDE_BACKGROUND
        | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS);
intent.putExtra("time-zone", zone.getID());
getContext().sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, UserHandle.ALL);
```